# Configuring Co-Authoring in SharePoint 2013 site collection?

Tags: designer-workflow, site-collection, excel, word, co-authoring

How do I configure Configuring Co-Authoring for SharePoint 2013 site collection for MS Word or Excel documents?

Answer (score 1):

This is the official documentation on co-authoring in SharePoint 2013: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718235.aspx

In a nutshell, you need the following:

- An Office Web Apps 2013 server;
- SharePoint 2013 configured to work with OWA 2013;
- A library to store documents for co-authoring;
- At least "Contribute" permissions for users who are meant to co-author documents in the library.
- Minor versions to be enabled for the document library;
- Require Check Out setting needs to be disabled for the document library - it is disabled by default;
- The "DisableCoauthoring" property of the web application where the site collection resides needs to be equal to false - it is false by default.
- All co-authors need to have Microsoft Word and Excel 2010 or 2013 installed on the computers they plan to co-author from.

Check [this article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff718248.aspx) out for setting the maximum number of co-uthoring authors, in case this is a concern.